# Which method will have higher priority?

Tags: wordpress

There are two approaches for limiting revisions in WordPress; WP_POST_REVISIONS and wp_revisions_to_keep(). Which will have higher priority ? I could not understand even after reading codex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WP_POST_REVISIONS` is constant, not a function. if you have set `WP_POST_REVISIONS` like this: `define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', 3 );` then you'll get 3 when you'll call the function `wp_revisions_to_keep` (provided that there is no filter who is modifying the value). If `WP_POST_REVISIONS` is not set then it will store every revision and you'll get `-1` when you'll call `wp_revisions_to_keep`. This is the source code of wp_revisions_to_keep.

```
/**
 * Determine how many revisions to retain for a given post.
 * By default, an infinite number of revisions are stored if a post type supports revisions.
 *
 * @since 3.6.0
 *
 * @uses post_type_supports()
 * @uses apply_filters() Calls 'wp_revisions_to_keep' hook on the number of revisions.
 *
 * @param object $post The post object.
 * @return int The number of revisions to keep.
 */
function wp_revisions_to_keep( $post ) {
    $num = WP_POST_REVISIONS;

    if ( true === $num )
        $num = -1;
    else
        $num = intval( $num );

    if ( ! post_type_supports( $post->post_type, 'revisions' ) )
        $num = 0;

    return (int) apply_filters( 'wp_revisions_to_keep', $num, $post );
}
```

From this, it is clear that function `wp_revisions_to_keep()` uses WP_POST_REVISIONS inside it. However, to be 100% sure that your suggested number of revisions work then you should hook a function to `wp_revisions_to_keep`. Something like this:-

```
add_filter('wp_revisions_to_keep', 'custom_revisions_number', 10, 2);
function custom_revisions_number($num, $post) {
    $num = 5; // <---- change this accordingly.
    return $num; 
}
```

Highest priority is of the hook that will execute last.